# Error when reading csv: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer

Tags: python, django, csv

I am receiving the following error when I am reading a csv file in my Django project.

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

I have searched the forum already, but could not find a solution to my problem. I also have no idea how to solve this. When I run this code locally I don't have the problem. Once I execute the script from my django views I get the error from above.

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

```
import os
from django.conf import settings

path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'technicalAnalalysis/EUR_USD')

def index(request):

    return render(request, 'technicalAnalysis/home.html')



class carouselData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):

        import csv

        EUR_USD_closeBid = []

        with open(path) as csvfile:

            readCSV = csv.reader(open(csvfile), delimiter=str(',').encode('utf-8'), )

            for row in readCSV:

                closeBid = row[0]

                BOP = row[12] 

                EUR_USD_closeBid.append(closeBid)

        data = {
            "EUR_USD_closeBid":EUR_USD_closeBid,

            }

        return Response(data)
```

this is how the csv was created

```
master.to_csv(eachCurrency, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

and this how the csv data looks like

```
1.4551,2016-08-25T21:00:00.000000Z,1.46613370302,1.4588,1.45146629698,19.2623252118,16.0468541889,18.0294990319,52.3305843166,-0.000955558790503,0.00497888833433,0.00402332954383,-0.228110599078
1.45557,2016-08-28T21:00:00.000000Z,1.46022799941,1.45683,1.45343200059,18.3020335848,15.2573095743,17.1424034245,52.7163692506,-0.00105527020367,0.00471507078342,0.00365980057975,0.655172413793
1.45919,2016-08-29T21:00:00.000000Z,1.459965965,1.456766,1.453566035,17.7461955078,14.6233407849,18.0619294336,55.6907414516,-0.000874414835166,0.00449646707462,0.00362205223946,0.82183908046
```

Thanks a lot in advance and kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the csv file twice. Remove the `open()` from this line:

```
readCSV = csv.reader(open(csvfile), delimiter=str(',').encode('utf-8'), )
```

to

```
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=str(',').encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already opened the file. You should read the file into memory then parse it with the csv library.

Otherwise, you can use `csv.reader` instead, so you can skip opening the file and let the library handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps csv.DictReader might also be helpful here. So for example:

```
with open(path) as f:
     data = list(csv.DictReader(f))
```